# Beautiful Soup Can't Find Tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to practice with the requests and BeautifulSoup Modules in Python 3.6 and have run into an issue that I can't seem to find any info on in other questions and answers.

It seems that at some point in the page, Beuatiful Soup stops recognizing tags and Ids. I am trying to pull Play-by-play data from a page like this:

http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609080den.htm

```
import requests, bs4

source_url = 'http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609080den.htm'
res = requests.get(source_url)
if '404' in res.url:
    raise Exception('No data found for this link: '+source_url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')

#this works
all_pbp = soup.findAll('div', {'id' : 'all_pbp'})
print(len(all_pbp))

#this doesn't
table = soup.findAll('table', {'id' : 'pbp'})
print(len(table))
```

Using the inspector in Chrome, I can see that the table definitely exists. I have also tried to use it on 'div's and 'tr's in the later half of the HTML and it doesn't seem to work. I have tried the standard 'html.parser' as well as lxml and html5lib, but nothing seems to work.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is there something in the HTML or its formatting that prevents BeautifulSoup from correctly finding the later tags? I have run into issues with similar pages run by this company (hockey-reference.com, basketball-reference.com), but have been able to use these tools properly on other sites.

If it is something with the HTML, is there any better tool/library for helping to extract this info out there?

Thank you for your help,
BF

Comment: what precisely do you want to parse from that table?
All table? only several columns? several cells?

Comment: your statement `table = soup.findAll('table', {'id' : 'pbp'})` isn't _not working_, it simply _doesn't find_ `div` elements with `id = pbp`

Comment: @DmitriyFialkovskiy I am trying to ultimately create an excel file of the plays from particular games. Once I can zero soup in on that table, I am confident I can loop to through tr and td tags to get the text out of it and use openpyxl to get it into excel. I guess ultimately my question is why doesn't bs4 find the tag in the html. It seems bs4 can find any tags before the comment in the html but not after - does the comment impact the parsing? is there any way to pull tags from after that comment accurately?

Comment: Both python GET and curl GET don't show that table (used grep to search). Perhaps that table is loaded async from the rest of the website?

Comment: If so, the javascript on the page will need to load first prior to scraping. This post seems to have a method of doing so - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python.

Comment: @qwertyuiop9 Thank You! That is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize the soup might not contain all of the html i was viewing through the browser. I will play around with Selenium or Dryscrape and see what I can figure out. Thanks again

Comment: @BigFore - Glad it helped! I will make my comment as an answer for others to see more easily.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BS4 won't be able to execute the javascript of a web page after doing the GET request for a URL. I think that the table of concern is loaded async from client-side javascript.

As a result, the client-side javascript will need to run first before scraping the HTML. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python) describes how to do so!

Comment: Thanks again, that was the issue. Playing around with Dryscrape helped. Guess I have another library to add to my list of things to learn.

Comment: As in October 2022, this answer seems to be quite outdated since those recommended packages are not maintained anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got what was the problem. You're trying to parse *comment*, not an ordinary html element.
For such cases you should use `Comment` from `BeautifulSoup`, like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,Comment

source_url = 'http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/201609080den.htm'
res = requests.get(source_url)
if '404' in res.url:
    raise Exception('No data found for this link: '+source_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')

comments=soup.find_all(string=lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment))

for comment in comments:
    comment=BeautifulSoup(str(comment), 'html.parser')
    search_play = comment.find('table', {'id':'pbp'})
    if search_play:
        play_to_play=search_play
```

Comment: @Big Fore, any feedback? does my answer help somehow?

Comment: Your answer is definitely helpful in my learning process, but wasn't the solution to the particular problem I had. My issue was with finding any tags after the comment. It turns out the HTML I was viewing in the browser after the comment was loaded via javascript so wasnt being shown in the requests text, but needed a further library to parse. Thank you for your help Dmitry

Comment: don't understand you completely - your purpose is to catch the comment itself with its text or tags _after_ the particular comment?