# BeautifulSoup does not see element , even though it is present on a page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape listings from Airbnb. Every listing has its own ID. However, the output of the code below is `None`:

```
import requests, bs4

response = requests.get('https://www.airbnb.pl/s/Girona--Hiszpania/homes?refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&query=Girona%2C%20Hiszpania&checkin=2018-07-04&checkout=2018-07-25&allow_override%5B%5D=&ne_lat=42.40450221314142&ne_lng=3.3245690859736214&sw_lat=41.97668610374056&sw_lng=1.7960961855829964&zoom=10&search_by_map=true&s_tag=nrGiXgWC')  
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

element = soup.find(id="listing-18354577")
print(element)
```

Why does the soup does not see this element, even though it is already loaded on the page?

Is it in a container of some type I need to scrape differently?

Comment: Can you please print the contents of `response.text` and it to your question?

Comment: Jared, it is very long and won't even fit into terminal. But posted above is a working code, would be so kind to try it instead?

Comment: See my answer below - if you inspect the contents of `response.text`, I think you'll see that it does not include `listing-18354577`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup Can't Find Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867425/beautiful-soup-cant-find-tags)

Answer (score 3):

`requests` don't wait for js, you can use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to load all page and after this use `bs4` for example this works:

```
import requests, bs4
from selenium import webdriver

# put the path to chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/to/chromedriver') 
website = "https://www.airbnb.pl/s/Girona--Hiszpania/homes?refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&query=Girona%2C%20Hiszpania&checkin=2018-07-04&checkout=2018-07-25&allow_override%5B%5D=&ne_lat=42.40450221314142&ne_lng=3.3245690859736214&sw_lat=41.97668610374056&sw_lng=1.7960961855829964&zoom=10&search_by_map=true&s_tag=nrGiXgWC"
driver.get(website) 
html = driver.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

element = soup.find(id="listing-18354577")
print(element)
```

**Output**

```
<div class="_1wq3lj" id="listing-18354577"> ...  #and many other data
```

Comment: Druta, this scraper is a Django web app. Since Selenium requires downloading the webdriver, is there any way I can use it within a web app? Like hosting the webdriver somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The element with id `listing-18354577` is created via javascript after the initial HTML page has loaded into your browser.  `Requests` is just an HTTP client, not a full-fledged browser engine, so it doesn't execute the Javascript that ends up fetching that element.  The response from `Requests` is just the initial HTML of the page (which does not include `listing-18354577`).