# I can't find an element using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a bot to scrape this page http://www.skysports.com/transfer-centre, when I open it in Chrome I can see the element I want in developer tool

[image: element]

but when I use the code below, it return None:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('http://www.skysports.com/transfer-centre').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('time'))
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps this element is being dynamically created via javascript.

Comment: If you print out `page` or `soup` and look at it, or View Source instead of inspecting the dynamic page in your browser, is that `<time>` tag there? If not, then it's not on the page (it was created by JS, as Gabriel said), so you can't find it on the page.

Comment: If that's the problem, there's almost certainly a good duplicate question—but the short version is that you're going to have to either run a JS interpreter (e.g., PhantomJS) or drive a web browser (e.g., see Selenium), or read the JS code and figure out what it's doing so you can do the same thing in Python, or trace the AJAX requests made by the JS code so you can make those requests in Python. (The last one will probably not get you the data in the same format as the dynamic web page, so you'll also need to figure out what the format is, but it may still be easier.)

Comment: If you're going to use a headless browser, don't use phantomjs, it's deprecated. Take a look at [this one instead](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome).

Comment: thank you all for pointing me to the right diretion, i ended up discovering selenium and chrome driver like @Gabriel suggested.

Comment: See also [python - Beautiful Soup Can't Find Tags - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867425/beautiful-soup-cant-find-tags) (although in this case it's possible to do it in a site-specific way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for extracting time from the url provided,
https://data.livefyre.com/bs3/v3.1/bskyb.fyre.co/363166/MTAwMDk1MTI=/init
Url I got from http://www.skysports.com/transfer-centre

```
import requests
import time
import json

page = requests.get('https://data.livefyre.com/bs3/v3.1/bskyb.fyre.co/363166/MTAwMDk1MTI=/init').json()
contents = page['headDocument']['content']
for content in contents:
    c = content['content']
    t = c['updatedAt']
    tt = time.strftime('%H:%M', time.localtime(t))
    authorId = c['authorId']
    bodyHtml = c['bodyHtml']
    print('time : {} , auther: {}'.format(tt, authorId))
    print('------------')
    print('bodyHtml: {}' , json.dumps(bodyHtml, None, 4))
    print('-----------\n\n')
```

Comment: thank you so much, the link you got has all the data i want, may i ask how you extracted it ?

Comment: The link is from the network calls while loading the page. I think the same can be done using python by opening web page or may be using selenium  and capturing the network calls( I didn't try it though) . And you were not getting the time tag from html because data  was coming through api call