# Table element not showing in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract table data from [this web site](https://www.vitalityservicing.com/serviceapi/Monitoring/QueueDepth?tenantId=1)

Following is the code--

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = requests.get('https://www.vitalityservicing.com/serviceapi/Monitoring/QueueDepth?tenantId=1')

soup = bs(page.text, "html.parser")

#None of the following method works
tb = soup.table 
#tb = soup.body.table
#tb = soup.find_all('table')
```

When I try to print `tb` its `None`

So I tried to look at  the `body` of the downloaded HTML with

```
print(soup.body.prettify())
```

I dont see the `table` elements or it's child elements . Only `<body>` and `<script>` elements are present:

[image: Output of print(soup.body)]

But when I inspect the page in chrome I see all the elements:

[image: table and it's child elements present while inspecting]

I don't understand why the `table` element is not being downloaded with `requests.get` while its there when I load  the page on chrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup Can't Find Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867425/beautiful-soup-cant-find-tags)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not getting that content because, when you execute the request, it is not present in the page. *Yet*.

If you check the javascript code between the script tags, you can see it is generating the table dynamically. So, you receive the html code before that has happened, since `requests` is not a browser and won't execute the js, and you don't get to see the table.

Now that you know why you can't see  the table, your next problem is how to get the HTML produced after the javascript execution. Don't faint, it is feasible. You might find the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597424/how-to-retrieve-the-values-of-dynamic-html-content-using-python) interesting.

Good luck

Comment: Yup, I figured it out and was using selenium webdriver to load the page. Solved my problem. Thanks