# Python: Parse multiple tables from webpage and group data in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I'm a total newbie at Python and have what I think is a pretty complex problem. I'd like to parse two tables from a website for about 80 URLs, example of one of the pages: https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/sam-darnold-1.html

I'd need the first table "Passing" and the second table "Rushing and Receiving" from each of the 80 URLs (I know how to get the first and second table). But the problem is I need it for all 80 URLs in one csv.

This is my code so far and how the data looks:

````
import requests
import pandas as pd

COLUMNS = ['School', 'Conf', 'Class', 'Pos', 'G', 'Cmp', 'Att', 'Pct', 'Yds','Y/A', 'AY/A', 'TD', 'Int', 'Rate']

urls = ['https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/russell-wilson-1.html',
        'https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/cam-newton-1.html',
        'https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/peyton-manning-1.html']
#scrape elements

dataframes = []
try:
    for url in urls:
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        #print(soup)
        table = soup.find_all('table')[0] # Find the first "table" tag in the page
        rows = table.find_all("tr") 
        cy_data = []
        for row in rows:
            cells = row.find_all("td")
            cells = cells[0:14] 
            cy_data.append([cell.text for cell in cells]) # For each "td" tag, get the text inside it

        dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame(cy_data, columns=COLUMNS).drop(0, axis=0))
except:
    pass

data = pd.concat(dataframes)
data.to_csv('testcsv3.csv', sep=',') ```


+---+--+----------------------+---------+-------+-----+----+-----+------+------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+-------+
|   |  |        School        |  Conf   | Class | Pos | G  | Cmp | Att  | Pct  |  Yds  | Y/A  | AY/A | TD  | Int | Rate  |
+---+--+----------------------+---------+-------+-----+----+-----+------+------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+-------+
| 1 |  |                      |         |       |     |    |     |      |      |       |      |      |     |     |       |
| 2 |  | North Carolina State | ACC     | FR    | QB  | 11 | 150 |  275 | 54.5 |  1955 |  7.1 |  8.2 |  17 |   1 | 133.9 |
| 3 |  | North Carolina State | ACC     | SO    | QB  | 12 | 224 |  378 | 59.3 |  3027 |    8 |  8.3 |  31 |  11 | 147.8 |
| 4 |  | North Carolina State | ACC     | JR    | QB  | 13 | 308 |  527 | 58.4 |  3563 |  6.8 |  6.6 |  28 |  14 | 127.5 |
| 5 |  | Wisconsin            | Big Ten | SR    | QB  | 14 | 225 |  309 | 72.8 |  3175 | 10.3 | 11.8 |  33 |   4 | 191.8 |
| 6 |  | Overall              |         |       |     |    | 907 | 1489 | 60.9 | 11720 |  7.9 |  8.4 | 109 |  30 | 147.2 |
| 7 |  | North Carolina State |         |       |     |    | 682 | 1180 | 57.8 |  8545 |  7.2 |  7.5 |  76 |  26 | 135.5 |
| 8 |  | Wisconsin            |         |       |     |    | 225 |  309 | 72.8 |  3175 | 10.3 | 11.8 |  33 |   4 | 191.8 |
| 1 |  |                      |         |       |     |    |     |      |      |       |      |      |     |     |       |
| 2 |  | Florida              | SEC     | FR    | QB  |  5 |   5 |   10 |   50 |    40 |    4 |    4 |   0 |   0 |  83.6 |
| 3 |  | Florida              | SEC     | SO    | QB  |  1 |   1 |    2 |   50 |    14 |    7 |    7 |   0 |   0 | 108.8 |
| 4 |  | Auburn               | SEC     | JR    | QB  | 14 | 185 |  280 | 66.1 |  2854 | 10.2 | 11.2 |  30 |   7 |   182 |
| 5 |  | Overall              |         |       |     |    | 191 |  292 | 65.4 |  2908 |   10 | 10.9 |  30 |   7 | 178.2 |
| 6 |  | Florida              |         |       |     |    |   6 |   12 |   50 |    54 |  4.5 |  4.5 |   0 |   0 |  87.8 |
| 7 |  | Auburn               |         |       |     |    | 185 |  280 | 66.1 |  2854 | 10.2 | 11.2 |  30 |   7 |   182 |
+---+--+----------------------+---------+-------+-----+----+-----+------+------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+-------+


And this is how I'd like the data to look, note the player name is missing from each grouping which ideally can be added from the sample website/url and I've added the second table which I need help appending:


+---+----------------+----------------------+---------+-------+-----+----+-----+------+------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+-------+----------------------+---------+-------+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+----+
|   |                |        School        |  Conf   | Class | Pos | G  | Cmp | Att  | Pct  |  Yds  | Y/A  | AY/A | TD  | Int | Rate  |        School        |  Conf   | Class | Pos | G  | Att | Yds | Avg | TD |
+---+----------------+----------------------+---------+-------+-----+----+-----+------+------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+-------+----------------------+---------+-------+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+----+
| 1 |                |                      |         |       |     |    |     |      |      |       |      |      |     |     |       |                      |         |       |     |    |     |     |     |    |
| 2 | Russell Wilson | North Carolina State | ACC     | FR    | QB  | 11 | 150 |  275 | 54.5 |  1955 |  7.1 |  8.2 |  17 |   1 | 133.9 | North Carolina State | ACC     | FR    | QB  | 11 | 150 | 467 | 6.7 |  3 |
| 3 | Russell Wilson | North Carolina State | ACC     | SO    | QB  | 12 | 224 |  378 | 59.3 |  3027 |    8 |  8.3 |  31 |  11 | 147.8 | North Carolina State | ACC     | SO    | QB  | 12 | 129 | 300 | 6.8 |  2 |
| 4 | Russell Wilson | North Carolina State | ACC     | JR    | QB  | 13 | 308 |  527 | 58.4 |  3563 |  6.8 |  6.6 |  28 |  14 | 127.5 | North Carolina State | ACC     | JR    | QB  | 13 | 190 | 560 | 7.1 |  5 |
| 5 | Russell Wilson | Wisconsin            | Big Ten | SR    | QB  | 14 | 225 |  309 | 72.8 |  3175 | 10.3 | 11.8 |  33 |   4 | 191.8 | Wisconsin            | Big Ten | SR    | QB  | 14 | 210 | 671 | 7.3 |  7 |
| 6 | Russell Wilson | Overall              |         |       |     |    | 907 | 1489 | 60.9 | 11720 |  7.9 |  8.4 | 109 |  30 | 147.2 | Overall              |         |       |     |    |     |     |     |    |
| 7 | Russell Wilson | North Carolina State |         |       |     |    | 682 | 1180 | 57.8 |  8545 |  7.2 |  7.5 |  76 |  26 | 135.5 | North Carolina State |         |       |     |    |     |     |     |    |
| 8 | Russell Wilson | Wisconsin            |         |       |     |    | 225 |  309 | 72.8 |  3175 | 10.3 | 11.8 |  33 |   4 | 191.8 | Wisconsin            |         |       |     |    |     |     |     |    |
| 1 |                |                      |         |       |     |    |     |      |      |       |      |      |     |     |       |                      |         |       |     |    |     |     |     |    |
| 2 | Cam Newton     | Florida              | SEC     | FR    | QB  |  5 |   5 |   10 |   50 |    40 |    4 |    4 |   0 |   0 |  83.6 | Florida              | SEC     | FR    | QB  |  5 | 210 | 456 | 7.1 |  2 |
| 3 | Cam Newton     | Florida              | SEC     | SO    | QB  |  1 |   1 |    2 |   50 |    14 |    7 |    7 |   0 |   0 | 108.8 | Florida              | SEC     | SO    | QB  |  1 | 212 | 478 | 4.5 |  5 |
| 4 | Cam Newton     | Auburn               | SEC     | JR    | QB  | 14 | 185 |  280 | 66.1 |  2854 | 10.2 | 11.2 |  30 |   7 |   182 | Auburn               | SEC     | JR    | QB  | 14 | 219 | 481 | 6.7 |  6 |
| 5 | Cam Newton     | Overall              |         |       |     |    | 191 |  292 | 65.4 |  2908 |   10 | 10.9 |  30 |   7 | 178.2 | Overall              |         |       |     |    |     |     | 3.4 |  7 |
| 6 | Cam Newton     | Florida              |         |       |     |    |   6 |   12 |   50 |    54 |  4.5 |  4.5 |   0 |   0 |  87.8 | Florida              |         |       |     |    |     |     |     |    |
| 7 | Cam Newton     | Auburn               |         |       |     |    | 185 |  280 | 66.1 |  2854 | 10.2 | 11.2 |  30 |   7 |   182 | Auburn               |         |       |     |    |     |     |     |    |
+---+----------------+----------------------+---------+-------+-----+----+-----+------+------+-------+------+------+-----+-----+-------+----------------------+---------+-------+-----+----+-----+-----+-----+----+

So basically I'd wanna append the second table (Only the columns mentioned) to the end of the first table and add the player name (read from the URL) to each row
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

COLUMNS = ['School', 'Conf', 'Class', 'Pos', 'G', 'Cmp', 'Att', 'Pct', 'Yds','Y/A', 'AY/A', 'TD', 'Int', 'Rate']
COLUMNS2 = ['School', 'Conf', 'Class', 'Pos', 'G', 'Att', 'Yds','Avg', 'TD', 'Rec', 'Yds', 'Avg', 'TD', 'Plays', 'Yds', 'Avg', 'TD']

urls = ['https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/russell-wilson-1.html',
        'https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/cam-newton-1.html',
        'https://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/peyton-manning-1.html']
#scrape elements

dataframes = []
dataframes2 = []
for url in urls:
    a = url
    print(a)
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    #print(soup)
    table = soup.find_all('table')[0] # Find the first "table" tag in the page
    rows = table.find_all("tr") 
    cy_data = []
    for row in rows:
        cells = row.find_all("td")
        cells = cells[0:14] 
        cy_data.append([cell.text for cell in cells]) # For each "td" tag, get the text inside it
    cy_data = pd.DataFrame(cy_data, columns=COLUMNS)

    #Create player column in first column and derive the player from the URL
    cy_data.insert(0, 'Player', url)
    cy_data['Player'] = cy_data['Player'].str.split('/').str[5].str.split('-').str[0].str.title() + ' ' + cy_data['Player'].str.split('/').str[5].str.split('-').str[1].str.title()
    dataframes.append(cy_data)

    table2 = soup.find_all('table')[1] # Find the second "table" tag in the page
    rows2 = table2.find_all("tr") 
    cy_data2 = []
    for row2 in rows2:
        cells2 = row2.find_all("td")
        cells2 = cells2[0:14] 
        cy_data2.append([cell.text for cell in cells2]) # For each "td" tag, get the text inside it
    cy_data2 = pd.DataFrame(cy_data2, columns=COLUMNS2)
    cy_data2.insert(0, 'Player', url)
    cy_data2['Player'] = cy_data2['Player'].str.split('/').str[5].str.split('-').str[0].str.title() + ' ' + cy_data2['Player'].str.split('/').str[5].str.split('-').str[1].str.title()
    dataframes2.append(cy_data2)

data = pd.concat(dataframes).reset_index()
data2 = pd.concat(dataframes).reset_index()
data3 = data.merge(data2, on=['index', 'Player'], suffixes=('',' '))
#Filter on None rows
data3 = data3.loc[data3['School'].notnull()].drop('index', axis=1)
display(data, data2, data3)
```

Comment: I think option 1, let me try it and see

Comment: Oh no, I need to add the second table from the page and append it after the last column, so transpose the second table

Comment: try the second version. Just replace the last four lines of code with other lines of code.

Comment: but there's no code for grabbing the second table and appending that data after the last column, that's the part I'm struggling with. Adding the player name looks like it's working well

Comment: got it. I think I lknow what you want now.

Comment: Yes sorry, the additional columns in the second data-set are all from a different table on the webpage (they look like the same)

Comment: Try the updated code. Unfortuantely, I cannot confirm it works. A second table is not showing up and my code is erroring out at `table2 = soup.find_all('table')[1]`. This may be because I have a slow internet connection. Does it work for you?

Comment: I get an IndexError: list index out of range on the second table, but not sure why yet, as it clearly exists on the page

Comment: same as me.  I think this is your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51897756/table-element-not-showing-in-beautifulsoup . The accepted answer is to go to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597424/how-to-retrieve-the-values-of-dynamic-html-content-using-python, which shows you how to use a selenium webdriver.

Comment: hmm so I almost have it working with selenium, problem is now with selenium it reads 17 columns instead of 14 but I don't know what the others are: ValueError: 17 columns passed, passed data had 14 columns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214946/discussion-between-mj95-and-david-erickson).