# BeautifulSoup does not show some tags in html page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

If I visit this page [here](https://mangadex.org/chapter/435396/2), I can see the image on the page with `img` tag upon inspection.

But when I try to get the page using `requests` and parsing with `BeautifulSoup` I can't access the same image. What am I missing here?

The code works fine, I get 200 as status_code from the request.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://mangadex.org/chapter/435396/2'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(page.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
img_tags = soup.find_all('img')
for img in img_tags:
    print(img)
```

EDIT::

As per suggestion, the selenium option works fine. But is there a way to speed it up as BeautifulSoup does?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beautiful Soup Can't Find Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867425/beautiful-soup-cant-find-tags)

Comment: @SuperShoot this does work as expected but is slow. Is there a faster way? Like, without visiting the page.

Comment: Will `PhantomJS` speed it up?

Comment: Usually if the page is being loaded with JavaScript there’s an api you call request directly to get the data in JSON format. Have a look in the network tab of you page inspection and see what resources are being used to pull data into the page.

Comment: @SuperShoot Thank you very much, analyzing the network call gave me the API request to make. How to accept your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use API to get images. Code below gets all images from the page and print urls:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Referer': 'https://mangadex.org/chapter/435396/2',
    'DNT': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) '
                  'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36',
}

params = (
    ('id', '435396'),
    ('type', 'chapter'),
    ('baseURL', '/api'),
)

response = requests.get('https://mangadex.org/api/', headers=headers, params=params)
data = response.json()

img_base_url = "https://s4.mangadex.org/data"
img_hash = data["hash"]
img_names = data["page_array"]

for img in img_names:
    print(f"{img_base_url}/{img_hash}/{img}")
```

Output:

> https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x1.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x2.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x3.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x4.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x5.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x6.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x7.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x8.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x9.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x10.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x11.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x12.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x13.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x14.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x15.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x16.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x17.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x18.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x19.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x20.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x21.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x22.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x23.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x24.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x25.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x26.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x27.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x28.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x29.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x30.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x31.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x32.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x33.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x34.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x35.png
>   https://s4.mangadex.org/data/ac081a99e13d8765d48e55869cd5444c/x36.png

Comment: this is exactly what I figured out with the comment of @SuperShoot. Thanks for the succinct code.

Comment: what is limit on this API usage?

Comment: @Doc I don’t know.

Answer (score 1):

The page has JavaScript that needs to run in order to populate some of the elements on the page. You could use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) to run the page's JavaScript before accessing the image.