# Not all HTML seems to be retrieved using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i'm quite new using BeautifulSoup, I have tried to retrieve a few elements in the following webpage: https://www.booking.com/hotel/tz/zuri-zanzibar.html

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.booking.com/hotel/tz/zuri-zanzibar.html"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content) 

for elem in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "facilitiesChecklistSection"}):
    try:
        print(elem.attrs['data-section-id'])
    except:
        continue
```

I get the following IDs, whereas there should be much more:

```
13
-2
2
7
11
16
22
21
23
25
26
34
1
```

Would you know why?
Also, i don't get anything back when i try:

```
soup.findAll("div", {"class": "hp_location_block__map_container bui-spacer--larger"})
```

I'd like to retrieve the map location.

Comment: i see only 14 `divs`  with class `facilitiesChecklistSection`  -  your code also prints these many `IDs`

Comment: remove `bui-spacer--larger` from the 2nd code you've shown , just try with `hp_location_block__map_container`

Comment: if you inspect on the URL, you can see ID 5 for Bathroom, or ID 17 for Bedroom. Still nothing regarding your 2nd comment

Comment: no i dint find any `data-section-id=5 or 17`

Comment: inspect using google chrome and you'll see them

Comment: From what I can see in google inspector, there are a total of 14 facilitiesChecklistSection div's and one among them does not have the attribute 'data-section-id' and hence only 13 are printed.

Comment: About the second point, this might help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867425/beautiful-soup-cant-find-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867425/beautiful-soup-cant-find-tags)

Comment: @MOHAMMEDNUMAN there are more than 14 facilitiesChecklistSection as you can see in the website: for example Bathroom, Bedroom, View, Outdoors, Kitchen, Room Amenities, Pets, Activities...

Comment: @JohnHoopHoop When I search the HTML for facilitiesChecklistSection I get only 14 entries.

Comment: @MOHAMMEDNUMAN so what is it for Bathroom, Bedroom, View, Outdoors, Kitchen, Room Amenities, Pets, Activities??

Comment: @JohnHoopHoop please provide a snap of it in the question.