# What is the <cbn-root> html element? And how to parser it by Java?

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I was trying to write a Java program to monitor if there are reserved spots becoming available on this website: https://www.drpciv.ro/drpciv-booking/formular/23/exchangingForeignDriverLicence

But when I view page source with Chrome or Edge, the body part show only `<cbn-root></cbn-root>`. But using Chrome's Inspect function I can see the complete body. When I try to get the content of the webpage in Java with HtmlUnit it gets only `<cbn-root></cbn-root>` and no real content either.

Tried to google `<cbn-root>`, but didn't see any useful information.
Wonder what the element  is and how to read the real content in Java in this case.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least with the upcoming version 2.43.0 the tag gets replaced.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String url = "https://www.drpciv.ro/drpciv-booking/formular/23/exchangingForeignDriverLicence";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX)) {
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
        System.out.println(" ---- ");
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10_000);

        System.out.println(" ---- ");
        System.out.println(page.asXml());
    }
}
```

Comment: When running this you will see a stack overflow in the logs, please use the latest SNAPSHOT build 2.44.0-SNAPSHOT to get this fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Beautiful Soup Can't Find Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867425/beautiful-soup-cant-find-tags)
It explains that the backend JS is loaded async and your GET request cant acutally get the tag. Read more here.