# bs4 parses the page correctly but find_all does not return anything

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the website

> https://www.automationanywhere.com/resources/customer-stories

I want to get the `href` of each `a` tag that is inside a `div` with class `storyInfoBox`.

If I print the results of the `lxml` parsing I can see what I'm looking for in the results.

However, find_all does not return anything. I've tried all of the below (all of which returned an empty list):

```
BeautifulSoup(requests.get(
    'https://www.automationanywhere.com/resources/customer-stories').content, 'lxml').find_all('a', text=' Read case Study')

BeautifulSoup(requests.get(
    'https://www.automationanywhere.com/resources/customer-stories').content, 'lxml').find_all('a', {'target', '_self'})

BeautifulSoup(requests.get(
    'https://www.automationanywhere.com/resources/customer-stories').content, 'lxml').find_all('div', {'class': 'storyBoxInfo'})
```

Comment: You must include a [example] in the question (so that it doesn't require the site to be working to demonstrate the issue)

Comment: Checkout [python - Beautiful Soup Can't Find Tags - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867425/beautiful-soup-cant-find-tags)

Comment: Try to add `.attrs` after `find_all()`. Then print it out and you will see a dictionary of the attribute. Then just get the `href` attribute's value.

Answer (score 0):

You want `storyInfoBox`, but then have it look for `storyBoxInfo`

Secondly, that doesn't even matter, as the page is dynamic and rendered through JS, so that won't even be in the initial html source.

You'll need to use something like selenium to let the page render first, THEN can get the html, or the json format is within the html `<script>` tag. Takes a little work to get into a valid json to read in, but it can be done:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

def replace_all(text, dic):
    for i, j in dic.items():
        text = text.replace(i, j)
    return text
d = {'true':'"True"', 'false':'"False"'}

url = 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/resources/customer-stories'
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

scripts = soup.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if'var customerDetails = ' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('var customerDetails = ')[-1].rsplit(';')[0]
        
        jsonStr = replace_all(jsonStr, d)
        jsonStr = re.sub(r'//"customerName".*?\n', r'', jsonStr)
        jsonStr = re.sub(r'//"customerQuote".*?\n', r'', jsonStr)
        old = ','
        new = ''
        maxreplace = 1
        jsonStr = new.join(jsonStr.rsplit(old, maxreplace))
        
        result = re.findall(r"\"itemId\": \d{0,9},", jsonStr)
        for each in result:
            jsonStr = jsonStr.replace(each, each[:-1])
            
        jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
        

links = []
for each in jsonData:
    customerName = each['customerName']
    caseStudy_link = each['caseStudy_link']['link']
    links.append(caseStudy_link)
```

**Output:**

```
print (links)
['https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/food-and-beverage-accounts-payable', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/financial-services/global-bank-hr', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/treasury-one', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/synergy-energy-provider', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/san-diego-county', '/solutions/manufacturing/quad-graphics-manufacturing', '', '/solutions/utilities/company-saves-25k-hours-with-rpa', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/healthcare/nhs-lowers-cost-with-rpa', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/data-storage-provider', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/technology/juniper-networks', '/solutions/financial-services/global-investment-bank', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/hgs-insurance', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/imaging-tools', '/case-study/chain-solution-company', '/solutions/manufacturing/ey-mining-customer', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/ey-banking-customer', '/case-study/global-credit-reporting-company', '/solutions/insurance/insurer-reduces-claims-processing-with-zero-errors', '', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/technology/core-digital-media', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/large-commercial-bank', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/large-commercial-bank', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/manufacturing/global-conglomerate', '/solutions/healthcare/global-medical-technology-company', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/images/casestudy/Everest_ANZ_practitioner_perspective.pdf', '', '/solutions/insurance/asia-largest-insurance-company', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/manufacturing/stant-automotive-supplier', '/solutions/lifesciences/boston-scientific', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/zs-professional-services', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/energy/cpfl', '', '', '', '', '', '/images/casestudy/Genpact_trucking_logistics.pdf', '', '', '/solutions/finance/bancolombia', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/pharmaceutical/eli-lilly', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/university-of-melbourne', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/technology/symantec-cyber-security', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/financeaccounting/cartus', '', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/media/australia-post', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/manufacturing/stanley-black-and-decker', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/bouygues-telecom', '/case-study/hitachi-vantara', '/solutions/financial-services/pggm-invoice-processing', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/ahold', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/financial-services/st-james-place', '', '', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/insurance/dai-ichi-life', '', '/case-study/tata-sky-content-distribution', '', '', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/vale', '/solutions/financial-services/pggm-rpa-drives-productivity', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/genworth', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/manufacturing/eastman-chemical-rpa', '/case-study/bpo-nga-hr', '/solutions/bpo/maximus', '/solutions/chemicals/nouryon', '/solutions/telecom/lyse', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/financial-services/monte-titoli', '/solutions/manufacturing/signify', '/case-study/law-practice/husch-blackwell', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '/solutions/financial-services/automation-challenge', '/solutions/hospitality/wam-group', '/solutions/manufacturing/nsg-group', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/technology/mcafee', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/it/volkswagen-india', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/financialservices/santandar-consumer-bank', '/solutions/telecom/canadian-telecom-company', '', '', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/healthcare/r1-rcm', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/manufacturing/eastman-purchase-order-processing', '/solutions/healthcare/healthcare-provider-processes-1-billion', '/solutions/finance-accounting/rpa-processes-university-finance-applications', '/solutions/case-study/dch-digital-transformation-with-rpa', '/solutions/healthcare/rpa-deployed-by-nhs-monitors-oxygen', '/solutions/case-study/university-of-melbourne', '/solutions/finance-accounting/tricor-uses-rpa-for-digital-transformation', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solution/covid-19/osv-manages-covid-processes-with-rpa', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/case-study/sprint', '/solutions/healthcare/rpa-helps-hologic-save-costs', '', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/technology/dell-uses-rpa-for-hr-processes', '/solutions/healthcare/physical-therapy-network-saves-costs-with-rpa', 'https://www.automationanywhere.com/solutions/finance-accounting/bae-systems-scales-processes-with-rpa', '/solutions/financial-services/keybank', '/solutions/healthcare/rpa-helps-vapotherm-combat-covid-19', '', '/solutions/financial-services/wustenrot-and-wurttenbergische-gruppe', '/solutions/financial-services/patelco-credit-union', '/solutions/manufacturing/great-lakes-tapes-rpa']
```