# Web Scaping | Python Selenium webdriver find dynamic elements using xpath

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Apologies in advance if this long question seems quite basic!

**Given**:

search query [link](https://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi/search?query=economic%20crisis&orderBy=RELEVANCE) in a library website:

```
url = 'https://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi/search?query=economic%20crisis&orderBy=RELEVANCE'
```

I'd like to extract all useful information for each individual search result (total 20 in 1 page) of this specific query as depicted by red rectangles in this figure:

[image]

currently, I have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

def run_selenium(URL):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222"),
    options.headless = True
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    
    driver.get(URL)
    pt = "//app-digiweb/ng-component/section/div/div/app-binding-search-results/div/div"
    medias = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, pt) # expect to obtain a list with 20 elements!!
    print(medias) # >>>>>> result: []
    print("#"*100)
    for i, v in enumerate(medias):
        print(i, v.get_attribute("innerHTML"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi/search?query=economic%20crisis&orderBy=RELEVANCE'
    run_selenium(URL=url)
```

**Problem**:

Having a look at part of the inspect in chrome:

[image]

I have tried several xpath generated by Chrome Extensions `XPath Helper` and `SelectorsHub` to produce XPath and use it as `pt` variable in my python code this library search engine, but the result is `[]` or simply nothing.

Using `SelectorsHub` and hovering the mouse over `Rel XPath`, I get this warning: `id & class both look dynamic. Uncheck id & class checkbox to generate rel xpath without them if it is generated with them.`

**Question**:

Assuming `selenium` as a tool for web scraping of a page containing dynamic attributes instead of `BeautifulSoup` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867425/beautiful-soup-cant-find-tags) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python), shouldn't `driver.find_elements()`, return a list of 20 elements each of which containing all info and to be extracted?

******>>>>> UPDATE <<<<<**** *Working Solution (although time inefficient)***

As recommended by @JaSON in the solution, I now use `WebDriverWait` in `try except` block as follows:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common import exceptions

def get_all_search_details(URL):
    st_t = time.time()
    SEARCH_RESULTS = {}
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True    
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    driver =webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    driver.get(URL)
    print(f"Scraping {driver.current_url}")
    try:
        medias = WebDriverWait(driver,timeout=10,).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'result-row')))
        for media_idx, media_elem in enumerate(medias):
            outer_html = media_elem.get_attribute('outerHTML')
            result = scrap_newspaper(outer_html) # some function to retrieve results
            SEARCH_RESULTS[f"result_{media_idx}"] = result
    except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException as e:
        print(f"Selenium: {type(e).__name__}: {e.args}")
        return
    except exceptions.NoSuchElementException as e:
        print(f"Selenium: {type(e).__name__}: {e.args}")
        return
    except exceptions.TimeoutException as e:
        print(f"Selenium: {type(e).__name__}: {e.args}")
        return
    except exceptions.WebDriverException as e:
        print(f"Selenium: {type(e).__name__}: {e.args}")
        return
    except exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException as e:
        print(f"Selenium: {type(e).__name__}: {e.args}")
        return
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Selenium: {type(e).__name__} line {e.__traceback__.tb_lineno} of {__file__}: {e.args}")
        return
    except:
        print(f"Selenium General Exception: {URL}")
        return
    print(f"\t\tFound {len(medias)} media(s) => {len(SEARCH_RESULTS)} search result(s)\tElapsed_t: {time.time()-st_t:.2f} s")
    return SEARCH_RESULTS

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://digi.kansalliskirjasto.fi
    get_all_search_details(URL=url)
```

This approach works but seems to be very time consuming and inefficient:

```
Found 20 media(s) => 20 search result(s) Elapsed_t: 15.22 s
```

Comment: Your question is not meeting SO rules. 1) Each question should be about one, specific issue, not a list of questions. 2) questions like is this tool is e best choice are opinion based and not allowed. 3) Is there tool / library questions are off-topic too.

Comment: I edited my question to fit  the SO regulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer for Question#2 only since #1 and #3 (as Prophet've already said in comment) are not valid for SO.

Since you're dealing with dynamic content `find_elements` is not what you need. Try to [wait](https://This%20is%20an%20answer%20for%20Question#2%20only%20since%20#1%20and%20#3%20(as%20Prophet%27ve%20already%20said%20in%20comment)%20are%20not%20valid%20for%20SO.%20%20Since%20you%27re%20dealing%20with%20dynamic%20content%20find_elements%20is%20not%20what%20you%20need.%20Try%20to%20wait%20for%20required%20data%20to%20appear:) for required data to appear:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

medias = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'media')))
```

Answer (score 0):

On top of the search results there is an option to download search results as excel, there comes the newspaper/journal metadata and the text surrounding the search. Could it be easier to use than scrape individual elements?   (Excel contains only 10.000 first hits, thou...)

[image: Load results as Excel file]

Comment: Problem with this approach is that I can't generate the link to csv automatically given a query url in my log file in python (I couldn't find the pattern link to csv)! That is why I am doing all web scraping for one page containing 20 search results using `html ` instead. Besides, CSV file does not provide highlighted words (in red color) in my page highlight.